# Difference Between Id and UID in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2010, ms-project-server-2013

i am new to microsoft project.i have to develop an app in another platform.i have many sample MS-project xml files.in all the files ID and UID value of Tasks is same.i want to know is there any sceario exist in which value of ID node will be different from UID Node in Task.Please respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation:

**UID**: The unique ID for the task.

**ID**: The position identifier of the task in the list of tasks.

I think they can be different...